# Stack template has some logical error for implementing binary tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, stack

i have a template of stack and a template of TreeNode (Binary Tree). Following is the code of two classes (stack and TreeNode). I succesfully inserted data into tree by using insert() function but there is a problem while retrieving it back using stack. Following are the compile time errors:

**Error 1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users\computer house\desktop\tree 1\tree 1\source.cpp    8   1   Tree 1**

**Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\computer house\desktop\tree 1\tree 1\source.cpp    8   1   Tree 1**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Stack{
private:
    TreeNode<T> *headNode, *pastCurrentNode;

public:
    Stack(){
        headNode = new TreeNode<T>;
        headNode=NULL;
    }

    void push(T x){
        TreeNode<T>* newNode = new TreeNode<T>;
        newNode->set(x);

        if(headNode != NULL){
            newNode->setNext(headNode);
            pastCurrentNode=headNode;
            headNode=newNode;
        }
        else{
            headNode=newNode;
            pastCurrentNode=headNode;
        }
    }

    T pop(){
        TreeNode<T>* p = new TreeNode<T>;
        p = headNode;
        headNode = pastCurrentNode;
        T x = p->get();
        delete p;
        return x;
    }

    T top(){return headNode->get();}

    bool isEmpty(){return (headNode == NULL);}
};

template<class T>
class TreeNode{
private:
    TreeNode* right, *left;
    T* object;


public:
    TreeNode(){
        this->left = this->right = NULL;
        object = NULL;
    }

    TreeNode(T* object){
        this->object  = object;
        this->left = this->right = NULL;
    }

    T* getInfo(){
        return this->object;
    }

    void setInfo(T* object){
        this->object = object;
    }

    TreeNode* getLeft(){return this->left;}
    void setLeft(TreeNode* left){this->left = left;}
    TreeNode* getRight(){return this->right;}
    void setRight(TreeNode* right){this->right = right;}

    int isLeaf(){
        if(this->left==NULL && this->right == NULL){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

};


void insert(TreeNode<int>* root, int* info){
    TreeNode<int>* newNode = new TreeNode<int>(info);
    TreeNode<int>*p, *q;

    p = q = root;

    while(*info != *p->getInfo() && q != NULL)
    {
        p = q;

        if(*info < *p->getInfo())
            q = p->getLeft();
        else 
            q = p->getRight();

    }

    if(*info == *p->getInfo()){
        cout<<"Error: Duplication: "<<*info<<endl;
        delete newNode;
    }
    else if(*info < *p->getInfo()){
        p->setLeft(newNode);
    }
    else{
        p->setRight(newNode);
    }
}



void sInOrder(TreeNode<int>* root){
    Stack< TreeNode<int>* > stack;
    TreeNode<int>* p;

    p=root;

    do{
        while(p != NULL){
            stack.push(p);
            p = p->getLeft();
        }
        //At this point left tree is empty

        if(! stack.isEmpty()){
            p = stack.pop();
            cout<<*p->getInfo()<<" ";
            //go back and traverse right subtree
            p = p->getRight();
        }
    }
    while(!stack.isEmpty() || p!=NULL);

}

int main(){

    int x[]={14,15,4,9,7,18,3,5,16,4,20,17,9,14,5,-1};
    TreeNode<int>* root = new TreeNode<int>;

    root->setInfo(&x[0]);

    for(int i=1; x[i]>0; i++){
        insert(root, &x[i]);
    }

    cout<<"\nStacked In Order: "; sInOrder(root);
    cout<<endl;


    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
TreeNode<T> *headNode, *pastCurrentNode;
```

but `TreeNode` is not declared prior to that line. You need to add either a forward declaration of `TreeNode` or the full definition of `TreeNode` before you can use `TreeNode<T>* headNode`.

Forward declaration:

```
template <class T> class TreeNode;
```

will suffice for the declarations of `headNode` and `pastCurrentNode`. However, it won't suffice for

```
Stack(){
    headNode = new TreeNode<T>;
    headNode=NULL;  // This is a problem anyway.
                    // You have just leaked memory.
}
```

In order to be able to use

```
    headNode = new TreeNode<T>;
```

you need the full definition of `TreeNode`.

Since `TreeNode` does not depend on `Stack`, my advice to you would be to move the complete definition of `TreeNode` before the definition of `Stack`.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

```
// Define TreeNode first.

template<class T>
class TreeNode{
private:
    TreeNode* right, *left;
    T* object;


public:
    TreeNode(){
        this->left = this->right = NULL;
        object = NULL;
    }

    // Add rest of TreeNode definition
};

// Now define Stack.

template<class T>
class Stack{
private:
    TreeNode<T> *headNode, *pastCurrentNode;

public:
    Stack(){
        headNode = new TreeNode<T>;
        headNode=NULL;
    }

    // Add rest of Stack definition

};
```

**PS** I noticed that you are using

```
    TreeNode<T>* newNode = new TreeNode<T>;
    newNode->set(x);
```

in `Stack::push`. However, there is no `set` function in `TreeNode`. You need to update your code appropriately for that to work.

Comment: sir I couldnt understood that solution. may you please provide the details of solved code snipet